# Kendo UI with MVC5 but with Foundation instead of Boostrap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc, zurb-foundation-5

I created a new ASP.NET MVC Webapp. I added foundation for MVC using Nuget package manager and removed the bootstrap package. At this point, everything is perfect.

I then added Kendo UI to the MVC Webapp just as I normally do. This is what my Index.cshtml page looks like for a simple test:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
        <h3>Content goes here</h3>

        <br/>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems like Foundation is somehow affecting the Kendo styles because the datepicker does not look how it should look. Does anyone have any ideas to why this could be happening? I purposely added anything related to KendoUI after Foundation to avoid this problem.

Here is my head tag in _Layout.cshtml

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    @*Set the viewport width to device width for mobile *@
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Welcome to Foundation</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/foundation/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")


    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

Here is right before the closing body tag in _Layout.cshtml

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/foundation")

<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
@*Use the Scripts section to define page specific scripts*@
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is to turn off bundle. Add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` in your `BundleConfig.cs` and reload your browser (F5) to make sure it is loading the fresh css instead of from cache. Also see if there is any script error or 404 error in the browser console too.

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. I also added the EnableOptimizations line to the BundleConfig.cs. It is still doing it. The kendo ui controls actually look very close to what they should, but there are just small styles that are throwing them off. I feel like I did everything correctly, but the kendo styles do not override all foundation styles like they do bootstrap styles. After inspecting element it looks like there is one foundation style: box-sizing: border-box; that could be causing some of my problems.